# Show type of param in template

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue, lvalue

I'm trying to get my head around reference collapsing (item 28 on [https://www.amazon.com/Effective-Modern-Specific-Ways-Improve/dp/1491903996](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996)), and want to play around with feeding different things to a template.

I call the template with lvalue and ravlue, but I don't see the exact types in the template. How can I get the compiler to spit out the exact types for the times it specializes the template?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Widget{
public:
    int x=0;
};


template<typename T>
void MyMethod(T&& param){
    std::cout << typeid(param).name()<< std::endl; // this just says 6Widget...
};

Widget GetWidget(){
    return Widget();
};

int main() {

    Widget &w1 = * new Widget;
    MyMethod(w1);

    Widget w2;
    MyMethod(w2);

    MyMethod(GetWidget());

    return 0;
}
```

This just outputs

```
6Widget
6Widget
6Widget
```

Is there any way for the compiler to spit out the exact specializations and types it made for the calls to the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really great book. Seems like you have jumped many chapters though.

In Item 4, you would see how you could do that with Boost.TypeIndex, with:

```
std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(param)>().pretty_name();
```